# UWP TreeView DragEnter and DragOver events do not execute

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop, treeview

It is very important that I can track which item is dragged in UWP TreeView and onto which item it is dropped. For now, I can get only item that is dragged. But I can not detect over which item it is dragged over or over which item it is dropped. Also it would be also good to know as preview which item is dropped onto so I can do more actions (for example cancel dropping on certain items).

Here is my extended control:

```
    public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    public MyTreeView()
    {
        this.DragItemsStarting += MyTreeView_DragItemsStarting; //execute ok
        this.DragItemsCompleted += MyTreeView_DragItemsCompleted; //execute ok

        this.DragEnter += MyTreeView_DragEnter; //does not execute?
        this.Drop += MyTreeView_Drop; //does not execute?
        this.DragOver += MyTreeView_DragOver; //does not execute?
    }

    //...
}
```

In the xaml:

```
<localdata:MyTreeView 
            x:Name="treeview" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding storageFolders,Mode=OneWay}" 
            Style="{StaticResource TreeViewStyle1}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding fileObject}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding IndexObj, Mode=TwoWay}"
            >             
        </localdata:MyTreeView>
```

Comment: Please note: Source and Target items are in the same TreeView.

Comment: It is by design , the `DragOver ` will invoked when other TreeView item over current TreeView.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT How can I then implement DragOver and other drag events when Source and Target items are within same TreeView?

Comment: If you need to implement DragOver and DragEnter within the same TreeView, please handle the DragOver and DragEnter event inside the TreeViewItem instead of the TreeView.

Comment: @AmyPeng-MSFT Please could you point me to code or examples how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is by design , the `DragOver` will be invoked when other `TreeView` item hover current `TreeView`. If you want to realize `cancel` feature, you could judge if current `TreeViewNode` is correct for `DragItems` in the `DragItemsCompleted` event handler like the following .

```
private void ListControl_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in args.Items)
    {

        var node = TreeDataBound.NodeFromContainer(TreeDataBound.ContainerFromItem(item));          
        var parent = node.Parent;

      //do some stuff judge the parent.
    }
}
```

Comment: Had tried to get parent node, but it returns null when casting item as TreeViewNode (item as TreeViewNode == null) ?

Comment: It is strange, could you share a simple project for us?

Comment: Here https://github.com/vladabuba/UWPTree1.git Here is event overriden in extended TreeView control, but it is the same here, or if I do it in window code behind.

Comment: zhu -MSFT I know which TreeViewItem is dragged and onto which TreeViewItem it is dropped to. My question is - How can I cancel Drop? Is there a property or method on TreeView or in args to cancel drop operation for current drop?

Comment: When DragStarting please use temp object to record current treeview itemsource. Then check if your drag item's parent is correct in drag completed event handler. if not, you could rollback the itemsource with temp object.

Comment: So you say I need to do that directly on the TreeView control and TreeViewItem control? Is there any way to do it in MVVM?

Comment: You need process the above in the TreeView  control, certainly you could use xaml [behavior](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) nuget to bind DragStarting  and DragComplted event in the view mode.

Comment: Hi, @NicoZhu I also faced the same problem target drop item is null and the UI has changed but the DB was okay. I used a temp object to hold the items but I can't delete the dropped item from the view(UI). It is not changing the data because when I relaunch the application it's okay.  Actually, I can't delete from null that's why it was in the UI. Do you have any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: You know I'm not handling UWP case any more. I recommand you make a new thread for your problem and add uwp or winui tag, and  msft will view the case then reply answer.