# How to prevent specific UWP TreeView node from reordering

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I include TreeView in my UWP application for Folder View support. But I want my root folder can't be dragged or any item can't be placed before my root folder.
Actually, I want to reorder any items except root.

[image]

Like the above picture, I want to reorder childNode one, two, or three but I don't want to re-order the root.

I don't want the below picture scenario.

[image]

How I can implement this in the UWP application?

Here is a sample of my code:

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<Page
    x:Class="TreeView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TreeView"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="KeywordTreeView"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Nodes}"
                  CanDragItems="True"
                  CanReorderItems="True">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Node">
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChildNodes}"
                                  IsExpanded="True"
                                  AllowDrop="True"
                                  CanDrag="True"
                                  Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
namespace TreeView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
            Node root = new Node("Root");
            Node childnodeone = new Node("ChildNode One");
            Node childnodetwo = new Node("ChildNode Two");
            Node childnodethree = new Node("ChildNode Three");

            root.ChildNodes.Add(childnodeone);
            root.ChildNodes.Add(childnodetwo);
            root.ChildNodes.Add(childnodethree);

            this.Nodes.Add(root);

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public Node(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> ChildNodes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with how I can implement this behavior in the UWP application programmatically?

Comment: Found a similar problem on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425746/uwp-treeview-dragenter-and-dragover-events-do-not-execute

Answer (score 1):

If you want to realize cancel feature, you could judge if current TreeViewNode is correct for DragItems in the DragItemsCompleted event handler like the following. When `DragStarting` please use **temp collection** to record current treeview itemsource. Then check if your drag item's parent is correct in drag completed event handler. if not, you could rollback the itemsource with temp object.

```
private void ListControl_DragItemsCompleted(ListViewBase sender, DragItemsCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var item in args.Items)
    {

        var node = MyTreeView.NodeFromContainer(MyTreeView.ContainerFromItem(item));          
        var parent = node.Parent;

      //do some stuff judge the parent.
    }
}
```

Comment: I reinserted the item from the parent information. But I can't reinsert the item in his previous position and the UI holds dragged the element.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written for drage and drop ?

Comment: For `DragItemsStarting` if `TreeViewDragItemsStartingEventArgs` object item count is greater than `0` then checking if it is `root` folder or not. If it is the root folder the  I called`EventArgs` Cancel. Otherwise, I save the `sourceNode` in a temporary variable.

Comment: For `DragItemsCompleted` if `TreeViewDragItemsCompletedEventArgs` event `DropResult` is `DataPackageOperation.Move` then from `sourceNode` I extracted the `parent Folder`, `indexToInsert`. Then reordered the folder structure with `sourceNode`, `targetNode` and `indexToInsert` parameter.

Comment: But when I `drag & drop` on top of `Root` Folder, I can't roll back as I am getting `targetNode` as `null` and `indexToInsert ` as `-1`.

Comment: If I forcefully inserted the `sourceNode` into the `targetNode` then the item is inserted in the last as I don't know the index where I should insert the element. But in UI the `drag` item is still present.

Comment: On top of that, I also called `OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))`. But no luck.

Comment: I mean you could re-set  treeview itemsource as temp collection to cancel previous drag option

Comment: I reload the Treeview items from DB to handle this scenario. Re-setting from temp somehow not working on my end. Maybe some wrong implementation. I will try it in the future. And thanks @Nico for your suggestion.

Comment: Fine, if you have any updates pleas feel free comment below.